# Password generation

Tags: password-cracking, hashcat, dictionary, crunch

I'm trying to generate all possible variation of a password.

The base word is like "PleaseSub!" and I need all possible version of it with uppercase, lowercase, etc.. I know there is something like 2^10 options but I can't figure out how to generate it with crunch or any other tool.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use hashcat to do so. You can write [rules](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=rule_based_attack) that will operate on your given wordlist (in this case, the single word "PleaseSub!", however it can be as many as you please) and generate a bunch of similar passwords according to your rules. e.g

`sXY - s will replace X with Y`

`$X - will append the character X to your wordlist`

`^X - will prepend the character X to your wordlist`

and so on, that link I provided will give you a bunch of different commands and how to utilise them effectively.

Example:

base_word.txt

```
PleaseSub!
```

please_sub.rule

```
se3       # Replace e with 3
sl1       # Replace l with 1
$1        # Append 1 to the generated password
$2        # Append 2 to the generated password
$3        # Append 3 to the generated password
```

Which can then be called like so `hashcat --stdout -r please_sub.rule base_word.txt`

Output

```
Pl3as3Sub!
P1easeSub!
PleaseSub!1
PleaseSub!2
PleaseSub!3
```

You can add multiple rules to a single line to have them all executed at the same time. E.g.

replace `se3` with `se3 sS5 $7`

and the output becomes:

```
Pl3as35ub!7
P1easeSub!
PleaseSub!1
PleaseSub!2
PleaseSub!3
```

You can skip generating the wordlist and just call it directly like so `hashcat -m <mode> hash.file base_word.txt -r please_sub.rule`

Writing your own rules can be quite difficult, so a helpful hint if you're trying this on Kali there are a bunch of pre-built rules in `/usr/share/hashcat/rules/`

E.g.

`hashcat -m <mode> hash.file base_word.txt -r /usr/share/hashcat/rules/best64.rule`

This is not an exhaustive list and I encourage you read through the page I sent you for a much more in depth look at generating rules.